# Multicollinearity question

Tags: multicollinearity

I have got a dataset with N=51. The dataset comprises two groups (n=26, and n=25).
I have one outcome variable and one covariate (both continues variables). I am interested in if there is an effect of group on outcome measure.

I used a general linear model to estimate the beta of group.

In the GLM, I  included the covariate. However, the covariate is significantly correlated with the dichotomous variable group (Pearson r=-.527, p(2-tailed)<.001), and the covariate is also marginally correlated with the outcome measure (Pearson r=-.269, p(2-tailed)=.056).

Because of this multicollinearity, I think I cannot interpret the effect of group. The beta value in the model without the covariate is relatively large and significant; in the model with the covariate, there is no effect of group (actually, beta group is very close to zero).

As far as I know, there is no good way to get rid of this multicollinearity (please correct me if I am wrong).
The next best thing that came to mind is estimating the effect of the covariate **within** the two groups. If the covariate indeed is a confounder, the estimates should be significant and similar in both groups, right?

I calculated the correlations of the covariate and the outcome measure for both groups, and got the following results:

Group A (n=26): Pearson r=-.047, p(2-tailed)=.819
Group B (n=25): Pearson r=-.354, p(2-tailed)=.082

Does this mean I can disregard the effect of the covariate, and go with the model that does not include the covariate?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you interested in whether the groups differ on the outcome measure, or whether the groups differ _controlling for_ the covariate?  You don't have a collinearity problem.
If the former, ignore the covariate, if the latter, put it in.

Comment: I think this question is about _confounding_, not collinearity. It would be good to know more about the distribution of the covariate (e.g. mean, sd) in each group. The correlation values you reported are not enough information, mainly because the numerical values assigned to the levels of the binary variable in the calculation are arbitrary, making the result not particularly meaningful (and is a reason I wouldn't call this collinearity, per se). Related to your other question, a differential effect of the covariate on the response in each group points more to _interaction_, not confounding.

Comment: Thanks guys. Here is some more information:

First:
The outcome measure is measured with an instrument of which the precision might slightly change over time. My covariate is the time since the measurement of the first participant. Because participants from group A and B have not been measured in a random order, (it was also **not** in perfect order: first the majority of A was measured, then the majority of B), I think I do need to put in the covariate. Do you agree?

Comment: Second: Here is some information on the distribution of the covariate: Group A: mean=290.5, sd=125.0; Group B: mean=166.2, sd=71.3. For more information about the distributions (e.g. skewness, curtosis, histrogram), I have uploaded a .pdf file: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6747155/Covariate_information.pdf

Comment: @Vincent, due to the large variance in this covariate, the apparently large mean difference - (290.5−166.2) - is probably more reflective of noise than anything. But, based on your first comment, it seems that this covariate would be more appropriately used to model _heteroskedasticity_ than a signal in the mean (which is what you're assuming by including it as a predictor).

Comment: @ Macro, I tested if there was heteroskedasticity in my model with the Koenker test for Heteroskdasticity in SPSS (http://www.spsstools.net/Syntax/RegressionRepeatedMeasure/Breusch-PaganAndKoenkerTest.txt). The Chi square test was not significant, indicating homoskedasticity. I furthermore looked at potential multicollinearity by calculating the Variation Inflation Factor, which was 1.4, indicating no multicollinearity. Having this extra information, what would you advise me to do?